# How to get weekly period delta from a single dynamic table

Tags: sql

We have a single table that stores project weekly cost information. Each week a snapshot of the cost history is saved and added below the previous week, resulting in one large table.

I am trying to run a query to see spend per project by period. However, as the history table is dynamic, when comparing previous weeks I end up with wrong values as new tasks/activities created this week, that have costs in them did not exist in the previous week. So when comparing the weeks, the new task are being ommitted.

This is the current code I am running:

```
SELECT 

A.ProjectID, 
A.TaskCode,
A.OBudget + A.ABudget AS [Total Approved Budget],
A.OBudget - B.OBudget AS [Budget Variance],
A.ForecastSales AS [Forecast Current],
A.ActualSales AS [Actuals Current]
B.ForecastSales AS [Forecast Previous], 
B.ActualSales AS [Actuals Previous],
A.ActualSales - B.ActualSales AS [Actuals Period],
A.ForecastSales - B.ForecastSales AS [Forecast Period],

FROM tblTask_History A
INNER JOIN tblTask_History B ON A.ProjectID = B.ProjectID AND A.TaskCode = B.TaskCode
WHERE A.ProjectID = '032401' AND A.Weekend = '2019-07-28' AND B.Weekend = '2019-06-30';
```

Because it is one table, I am essentially duplicating it and using the differnt weekend to get period data.

For example actual sales may be $100 to-date. If I enter in the dates from 11/7/19 to 22/08/19 actual sales may equate to $100, which is correct. But if I enter in 2/7/19 to 22/08/19 then actual sales may be $50, which is incorrect, as we know $100 is what has been spent to date.

The reason I am receving this errornous value is due to a task code not existing in that time period, so therefore it excludes it from the query.

I have attempted to union the table, create cases where B.Taskcode = NULL then A.Taskcode.

However nothing seems to fix the problem.

Here is an example of the history table:

```
| Weekend    | ProjectID | TaskCode | TaskDes                             | Obudget     | Abudget     | ForecastSales | ActualSales |
|------------|-----------|----------|-------------------------------------|-------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|
| 15/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode1 | Project Team                        | $16,565.13  | $16,565.13  | $120,387.99   | $7,048.92   |
| 15/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode2 | Engineering                         | $26,751.29  | $26,751.29  | $136,756.53   | $5,339.17   |
| 15/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode3 | Mechnical Team                      | $9,858.49   | $9,858.49   | $141,234.16   | $5,375.61   |
| 15/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode4 | Process Dynamics                    | $5,088.67   | $5,088.67   | $33,030.90    | $5,164.70   |
| 15/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode5 | Subcontracts                        | $-          | $-          | $7,048.92     | $5,375.61   |
| 15/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode6 | Instrument / Electrical Engineering | $15,780.39  | $15,780.39  | $5,339.17     | $5,164.70   |
| 22/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode1 | Project Team                        | $32,468.80  | $32,468.80  | $5,375.61     | $1,998.88   |
| 22/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode2 | Engineering                         | $42,407.53  | $42,407.53  | $5,164.70     | $(0.00)     |
| 22/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode3 | Mechnical Team                      | $3,478.80   | $3,478.80   | $196,306      | 45.4        |
| 22/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode4 | Process Dynamics                    | $10,000.00  | $10,000.00  | $15,754       | 20835.44    |
| 22/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode5 | Subcontracts                        | $134,000.00 | $134,000.00 | 2835.77       | 15112.41    |
| 22/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode6 | Instrument / Electrical Engineering | $18,585.26  | $18,585.26  | 0.0001        | 3498.88     |
| 22/06/2019 | 556VVD    | TSKCode6 | Fabrication                         | $15,109.31  | $15,109.31  | 403.5891      | 4147.03     |
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just need `lag()`:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM SELECT h.ProjectID, h.TaskCode,
            (h.OBudget + h.ABudget) AS [Total Approved Budget],
             h.OBudget - ALG(h.OBudget, 4, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY h.ProjectId, h.TaskCode ORDER BY h.Weekend) AS [Budget Variance],
             h.ForecastSales AS [Forecast Current],
             h.ActualSales AS [Actuals Current]
             LAG(h.ForecastSales, 4) AS OVER (PARTITION BY h.ProjectId, h.TaskCode ORDER BY h.Weekend) [Forecast Previous], 
             . . .
      FROM tblTask_History h
      WHERE h.ProjectID = '032401' 
     ) h
WHERE h.Weekend = '2019-07-28' ;
```

The only real trick is to use a subquery so you can filter by the date that you want.

Note:  This assumes that once records are added for a given project/task, there is exactly one per week.